# Insert data to MySQL with Ajax in Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, laravel

I have a JS variable which store a JSON value in my blade view and I want to insert it to MySQL in Laravel project. But I don't know how to write it right. This is what I tried in my blade view:

```html
<body>
    <div id="fb-editor"></div>

    <div id="saveToDatabase">
      <button id="saveBtn" type="button">Save To Database</button>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
  var formBuilder = $('#fb-editor').formBuilder();

  

  $("#saveBtn").click(function() {
   var mFormData = formBuilder.actions.getData(); //my JSON data 
   
   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/saveToDatabase',
    data: {"mFormData":mFormData}
   }).done(function (msg) {
    alert("Data saved!");
   });
  });
  
</script>
```

But when I run it, it appear error said: jquery.js:8630 POST http://localhost/saveToDatabase 404 (Not Found).

How I can fix this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you defined the route in routes/api.php?

Comment: I only write code in blade view so I think I can use default route in web.php. Am I wrong?

Comment: You using Laravel then why do you code use `mysqli_connect`?

Comment: That is my 2 .php file I put in xampp htdocs folder to run. I just show it for you to understand what I am doing. I want to do that in Laravel.

Comment: appears because the route in laravel is not defined in web.php. Have you add the route in web.php ?

Comment: I just write ajax code in blade view, I don't have any controller, how I can write route?

Answer (score 2):

First, enter your database details on .env file.

You need to use two routes. One for the blade file to render and another for the api request.

On routes/web.php, define your route,

```
Route::get('/', function(){ return view('app');});
```

Create app.blade.php in resources/views/ folder with your HTML code.

On routes/api.php, define your route like this

```
Route::post('saveToDatabase','HomeController@saveToDb')
```

Next, you need to create saveToDb method on the HomeController.

Open App\Http\Controller\HomeController.php

Create a new method

```
public function saveToDb()
{
  // Database Insertion Code goes here

}
```

Laravel Provide CSRF Protection to the POST request. So add Exception to this route by adding it in the App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCSRFToken.php

```
  protected $except = [
        'api/*'
    ];
```

For the insertion operation, we can do this with the help of the model.

So first create Form.php in App\ folder.

Inside that, we specify the fields of the database.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Form extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        "key", "data"
    ];

    protected $hidden = [];

}
```

Next, we can use this model to insert data to the Form table.

In your HomeController.php at the top

```
use App\Form;
use Request;
```

Now we can update the saveToDb function that we write before.

```
public function saveToDb()
{
  // Request all the post data
  $req = Request::all();    
  // From that post data store key and data part to form table
  Form::create($req);
}
```

If you have any issue in route, controller or model. Refer Laravel official docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing

And this one is also useful to get started to laravel. https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2018

Comment: Hmm where I should write insert query?

Comment: Yes. Instead of model, you can use like this $values = array('key' => 1,'data' => 'Dayle');
DB::table('form')->insert($values);

Comment: But my JSON values is stored in a JS variable in blade view which is var mFormData = formBuilder.actions.getData(); //JSON data return. How I can use this in query?

Comment: When you write return $data; in the controller method. It will return the json data.  Do you want to return the data from the database to json?

Comment: Maybe you are misunderstand my problem. I edited my post. I have a JS variable which is store my JSON values. Now I want to insert that JSON values to my database. I don't need to return data form the database. I configed in .env file like you say and created model and controller. What should I do next? Thank you!

Comment: I think because that url don't have in web.php. But I write only ajax in blade view, I don't have any controller and function, I don't know how to write route for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194219/discussion-between-jijin-p-and-tomato).

Answer (score 0):

The route is not selected correctly. http://localhost/saveToDatabase is not find for do something

Comment: Yes. I think because that url don't have in web.php. But I write only ajax in blade view, I don't have any controller and function, I don't know how to write route for this.

Comment: Jijin P say how do this in above. remember post need CSRF in laravel.